# Creating a Form like application in .NET

Tags: .net

I want to know what goes into creating a Form designer using VS.
Basically the application would have a Toolbar with controls that can be dropped. The controls should have the minimum properties of adding/editing/deleting text. Currently I want the user to have the ability to add a Label, TextBox and a Button. Should be able to move/place the controls on the form. Should be able to delete the controls. The current state of the form can be save to a xml maybe.

Please give me pointers or links where I can get started.

Regards.

Comment: That means you want to develop a IDE like visual studio

Comment: Well not exactly an IDE. Contextually the user will create a layout and there will be no communication between the controls as one would have/create through VS. This will be a very low level customization screen where the user can create lables, textboxes and groupboxes and save the layout

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need proper understanding of Mouse-X and drag-X events. Along with this, you might need to use Paint (although I do not see that necessary). [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13272/Crafting-a-C-Forms-Editor-from-scratch) article would be a nice place to begin with.

Next, PropertyGrid control would come in handy once control is created. Here's a basic concept of how it may work:

1. A set of images which represent controls that your IDE supports.
2. MouseDown event handlers for the buttons to track which one was clicked and the click location.
3. MouseMove event handler to track where user is dropping it into container.
4. MouseUp event handler to know user has dropped the control. In the same handler, add a control to the container. For instance, if user picked up label and dropped it, add a label to container (standard panel control) through code.
5. Now, add drag drop related events to enable moving of control.
6. On click, load a PropertyGrid with controls property.
7. When the user saves the form, check all the controls and create a CS/VB file (for it is supported by other IDEs too) and save it at some location.